# How to start Apache on EC2

Tags: php, apache, webserver, amazon-ec2

I'm an absolute newbie to EC2. My goal is to run a php-mysql-website on EC2.

I've just setup a new instance based on [this ami](http://thecloudmarket.com/image/ami-6c576218--amazon-public-images-suse-linux-enterprise-server-11-sp1-32-bit)

It seems that apache isn't running? How do I start apache? Is there a general tutorial on how to start EC2 as a web server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Suse 11, try

```
 rcapache2 status
 rcapache2 start
```

If it is not installed, you can install with

```
yast2 --install apache2
```

for a tutorial on LAMP with this server, check

http://www.susegeek.com/internet-browser/install-configure-lamp-apachemysqlphp-in-opensuse-110/

Comment: Your last command results in "No such client module –install" Is there a preconfgured AMI where a LAMP is already installed?

Comment: I don't believe so, you may have to follow a tutorial online to get the stack set up. Don't worry, after a few tries, you'll have the hang of it for good.

Comment: sorry, typo. two hyphens, or -i

Comment: Just wanted to mention that BitNami does provide Amazon and Azure cloud images with pre-configured LAMP. http://bitnami.com/stack/lamp/cloud

Answer (score 9):

It really depends on the distribution you have chosen.  Typically, though, you can start Apache using the init scripts.  For example, on Ubuntu server it will be:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

On CentOS or Redhat it might be:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/httpd start
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to set up a LAMP server. To install LAMP server with one command, try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

Note that the last `^` is not a typo, it's included in the command. See [this](http://tuxtweaks.com/2011/10/install-lamp-and-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-11-10/) page for more information.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get update
sudo tasksel

and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running bitnami's Drupal Stack, you can

1) cd /opt/bitnami
2) sudo bash
(enter password)
3) sh ctlscript.sh restart

this will restart the LAMP stack